# Using Visual Studios on windows to send app to iphone

Tags: iphone, windows, visual-studio-setup

I recently got Visual studios up and running on my windows 7 32 bit computer. After searching online for a simple "Hello World" single view app tut, I now want to either put it on my phone or run a simulation of it. Anything i try searching online for this usually ends in a "omg this is a cross platform thing. blah bla blha" and I really can't find much on a mac-less solution. I do not have a mac and cannot use one to run the simulation. I also don't want to send the app through the app store.

So, is there any windows from step one to final solutions to using the app I made in visual studios? I am pretty knowledgeable about java and have been using eclipse for a while, so any analogies that can be made with that and the new process would be helpful.

Comment: Apple won't let you run their OS in a simulator/emulator on Windows. While you can test your app on Windows and Android using the emulators that come as extensions to the IDE, you don't get that luxury with iOS.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being illiterate, I have only started dealing with cross platform operation, but I couldn't figure out how to export the program to my phone as well. Would you know how to do that?